# Calculate time using vue-moment

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

I faced a problem while trying to calculate between 2 different times.
I am using vue-moment, and i tried to calculate the time with diffs but with no success.

```
data() {
  return {
            date: moment('12-11-2019').format("DD-MM-YYYY"),
            date2: moment('13-11-2019').format("DD-MM-YYYY"),
            startTime: this.date.diff(this.date2)
```

what is the right way of using moment in data and methods?

P.S.
i want to calculate the hours also and parse it with the date in the same argument, but i couldnt do it right.

Comment: you cannot access `data` stuff  while defining `data` stuff, (you could write a dataInit function, calc what you need, and then return the data)

Comment: you mean use it in the computed?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to make it work with a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) no problem:

```
computed: {
  startTime() {
     return this.date.diff(this.date2);
  }
}
```

<kbd>[**Working example**](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-cv0fp?fontsize=14)</kbd>

Comment: Error in render: "TypeError: this.date1.diff is not a function"

Comment: That's because you are running `.format` on your dates, which returns a string. And you can't call `diff` on strings. I've added a working example.